# Реализация таймера golang

Tags: golang, таймер

Не могу разобраться в работе таймера в golang. Есть условие которое если соблюдено отправляется в другую функцию, которая возвращает либо ошибку, если что-то пошло не так, либо nil если все ок. Если что-то идет не так то ответ идет очень долго (функция дергает инициализацию устройтсва на com-порте), если устройство есть, то инициализация просисходит моментально.
Созрел план просто сделать таймер: если инит не прошел быстро, то переставать ожидать ответ от устройства и возвращать nil.

```
if !condition {
    if func() == nil {
        condition = true
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно это реализовать? Я непонимаю как работают таймеры и горутины. За ранее всем большое спасибо

Comment: Возможно вам пригодится [context](https://go.dev/blog/context).

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать функцию `time.After()` для создания таймера. Эта функция возвращает канал, который закрывается через указанное время. Вы можете использовать конструкцию `select` для ожидания возврата либо результата функции, либо таймаута.

```
select {
case res := <- func():
    if res == nil {
        condition = true
    }
case <- time.After(time.Second * 3):
    // таймаут, выходим из функции
}
```

В этом примере функция `func()` возвращает канал, который закрывается, когда функция завершает работу. Если функция возвращает `nil`, то условие condition становится `true`.

---

В этом примере мы создаем контекст с таймаутом 5 секунд. Затем мы запускаем горутину для инициализации устройства, который иммитирует ваше поведение.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // создаем контекст с таймаутом
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*5)
    defer cancel()

    // создаем горутину для инициализации устройства
    var condition bool
    initDevice := func() error {
        // имитируем длительную инициализацию
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
        condition = true
        return nil
    }
    go func() {
        if !condition {
            if initDevice() == nil {
                condition = true
            }
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Initialization timeout")
    case <-time.After(time.Second * 15):
        fmt.Println("Initialization successful")
    }
}
```